# Mockito - NullpointerException when using doAnswer().when() on mocked interface

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I am writing Junit tests for my Android module and running it with help of `RobolectricTestRunner`. I have mocked an interface `AuthenticationChannnel` with the name `authenticationChannel1` and want to perform some actions on some defined objects on invocation of a method on `authenticationChannel1`. I am using `Mockito.doAnswer(..).when(authenticationChannel1).<method>()` capability of Mockito.

The first stubbing for a method inside my `@Before` method goes through fine. When I try to stub another method in one of my test cases, I get `NullPointerException`. Here is my code:

```
    @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
    public class AuthenticationManagerTests {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final Context context = RuntimeEnvironment.application;

    private final WeakReference<Context> contextWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);

    @Mock(name="channel1")
    AuthenticationChannel authenticationChannel1;

    Event<AuthChannelEvent> authChannel1Event;

    @Mock(name="channel2")
    AuthenticationChannel authenticationChannel2;

    Event<AuthChannelEvent> authChannel2Event;


    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    @Before
    public void before() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        authChannel1Event = new Event<>();
        authChannel2Event = new Event<>();

        // Setting up the event handlers for the channel 1
        Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
            authChannel1Event.addEventHandler(invocation.getArgument(0));
            return null;
        })
                .when(authenticationChannel1) // This runs just fine ..
                .subscribeToAuthenticationChannelLifecycleEvent(any());

        // Setting up the event handlers for the channel 2
        Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
            authChannel2Event.addEventHandler(invocation.getArgument(0));
            return null;
        })
                .when(authenticationChannel2)
                .subscribeToAuthenticationChannelLifecycleEvent(any());

        countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        final List<AuthenticationChannel> authenticationChannels = new ArrayList<>();

        authenticationChannels.add(authenticationChannel1);
        authenticationChannels.add(authenticationChannel2);

        authenticationManager = // Initializing the object with the implementation to test ..

        // Setting up global mock methods ..
        Mockito.when(authenticationChannel1.getChannelIdentifier()).thenReturn("channel1");
        Mockito.when(authenticationChannel2.getChannelIdentifier()).thenReturn("channel2");


        // Mocking encryption key from authentication channels ...
        try {
            Mockito.when(authenticationChannel1.getEncryptionKeyElseAuthenticate(any(), any()))
                    .thenReturn(KeyUtil.getSecureRandomBytes(CryptoConstants.KEY_SIZE_128 / 8));
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Mockito.when(authenticationChannel2.getEncryptionKeyElseAuthenticate(any(), any()))
                    .thenReturn(KeyUtil.getSecureRandomBytes(CryptoConstants.KEY_SIZE_128 / 8));
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Setting context to the authentication channels ..
        authenticationChannel1.setTriggeringContext(context);
        authenticationChannel2.setTriggeringContext(context);

    }

    @Test
    public void test_SetupChannel1() {

        final boolean[] setupSuccess = {false};

        Mockito.when(authenticationChannel1
                .isAuthenticationChannelUsagePossibleOnDevice()).thenReturn(true);
        Mockito.when(authenticationChannel2
                .isAuthenticationChannelUsagePossibleOnDevice()).thenReturn(true);

        // Setting up the event for authentication manager ...
        authenticationManager.subscribeToAuthenticationManagerLifecycleEvent(new Event.EventHandler<AuthManagerEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void run(AuthManagerEvent authManagerEvent) {
                if(authManagerEvent.getEventName().equals(AUTH_MANAGER_SETUP_SUCCESS)) {
                    setupSuccess[0] = true;
                }
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public Executor getExecutor() {
                return MoreExecutors.directExecutor();
            }
        });

        // Intercepting the call of the setup method for the authentication channel ..
        Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
            // Intercepting the call of calling of the authentication channel 1 and raising event
            // for success ...
            authChannel1Event.raiseEvent(new AuthChannelEvent(
                    CHANNEL_SETUP_SUCCESS,
                    "channel1",
                    new AuthPurpose(AuthenticationPurpose.
                            PURPOSE_SETUP,
                            "channel1",
                            false
                    )
            ));
            return null;
        })
                .when(authenticationChannel1) // Getting NullPoinnterException here ..
                .setUpAuthenticationChannel(any(), any());

                ..............
    }

}
```

Can someone point out where I could go wrong here? I went over an interesting post:https://medium.com/kenshoos-engineering-blog/mockito-gotcha-beware-of-method-invocation-when-stubbing-65cf5cf2e4af. Although this is quite similar to my case but with using another mocking way with Mockito.

**EDIT 1**
Adding stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at in.zeta.apollo.encryptedstore.AuthenticationManagerTests.test_SetupChannel1(AuthenticationManagerTests.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:176)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:142)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: you don't seem to instantiate authChannel1Event

Comment: @stultuske I have done that already inside before method.

Comment: Please also post the *complete* stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you fell into a special case of Mockito.

You use the more readable form of stubbing (with different spacing):

```
Mockito.when(
    authenticationChannel1
      .isAuthenticationChannelUsagePossibleOnDevice()
            ).thenReturn(true);
```

The problem here is that Mockito cannot change the order in which the statements are executed. So your method `isAuthenticationChannelUsagePossibleOnDevice` is executed first and *Mockito* replaces the result before it is passed to your *Code under Test*. In turn this leads to a `NullÜointerException` if your method `isAuthenticationChannelUsagePossibleOnDevice` accesses any member variable of `authenticationChannel1` since *Mockito* initializes them with `null`.

You have two options:

1. Change your stubbing to the second form *mockito* provides:

   ```
   Mockito.doReturn(true)
          .when(authenticationChannel1)     
          .isAuthenticationChannelUsagePossibleOnDevice();
   ```

When using this form the original method in your dependency is not called.

2. Don't use a *mock*,  but a *spy* instead. In that case you create a normal instance from your dependency including its (transitional) dependencies an wrap it in a spy object. This means much more work and should be the last resort...

Comment: `authenticationChannel1` is not a concrete class. It is a mock of an interface. Also, I tried changing all the invitations to the way you mentioned. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you further help here. I am still stuck with this

Comment: @Swapnil Your stacktrace indicates line 186 in `AuthenticationManagerTests.java` being the place with the problem. What is that particular line? (**Attention!** take the line number from your **current** stacktrace!)